# IE Problem with rollover images

Tags: internet-explorer

www.bsmdrivinglesson.com

I'm testing the above site on different browsers.

There is a problem with the Menu buttons on IE.
Does anyone know the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested the site on 4 browsers and the top nav menu all rendered properly but you had other issues on the page. Some of your content looked skewed, possibly to the left. I can send you a screen shot if you want?  Have you changed something since you posted this?

But to answer your question web standards are not high enough to the point where all browsers render or parse the data the same. Review the syntax of your code closely. Usually some fine tweaking will fix the problem. Try removing any extra code that may have been applied if you are using a wysiwyg editor.

Comment: Thanx Rob. Yes Pls I would like to see the screenshot.
And No, I havn't changed anything since I posted this.

Comment: I need an email or something to get a hold of you. The problem seems to be in your java script possibly. The mouse out and in events may be throwing IE. I am not an expert at Java but I use html and css every day for my job and I can assure it seems IE throws the most errors.

Comment: btw I used dreamweaver's inbult js for the menu buttons